# ActiveAdmin remove fieldset wrap from nested block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

I’m building a form with ActiveAdmin that allows users to add a `Quote` as a nested attribute inside of a `Job` form. I want to combine attributes from both the `Quote` and `Job` into the same form block.

I have this working successfully, however my nested `:quote` block renders a nested `fieldset` element to go with it. I just want it to render the `li` elements, none of the wrapping bits.

My current code looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Job do

  form do |f|

  f.inputs "Quote Details" do

    f.inputs "", :for => [:quote, f.object.quote || Quote.new] do |f|
      f.input :quote, :input_html => { disabled: !current_admin_user.role?(:admin) }, hint: f.object.quote.present? ? link_to(f.object.quote.identifier, f.object.quote.url) : false
      f.input :quote_cache, as: :hidden
      f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean if f.object.quote.present?
    end

    f.input :quote_accepted# if f.object.quote.present?
    f.input :quote_accepted_date, as: :datepicker# if f.object.quote_accepted

  end

  end

end
```

How would I edit it so that the `:quote` block has no wrap around it?

Comment: Have you tried `f.fields_for :quote do |q|`?

Comment: Unfortunately that returns me the error `undefined method 'quote' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: How exactly did you use it?

Comment: I have managed to get myself halfway there. I have updated the question to reflect where I’m at with it. Any ideas how I might be able to remove the wrapping `fieldset` element from the nested block?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I had the same issue and this answer may help somebody.

I couldn't render just one fieldset but I fix it by editing the css style of the second `f.inputs`. I added a `style: 'border: none'` to the second `f.inputs`. You can add a class instead of the inline style.

Something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Job do

  form do |f|

  f.inputs "Quote Details" do

    f.inputs :for => [:quote, f.object.quote || Quote.new], style: 'border: none' do |f|
      f.input :quote, :input_html => { disabled: !current_admin_user.role?(:admin) }, hint: f.object.quote.present? ? link_to(f.object.quote.identifier, f.object.quote.url) : false
      f.input :quote_cache, as: :hidden
      f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean if f.object.quote.present?
    end

    f.input :quote_accepted# if f.object.quote.present?
    f.input :quote_accepted_date, as: :datepicker# if f.object.quote_accepted

  end

  end

end
```